# Problems Interoping C++ (DLL) with C# console app

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to interop C++ DLL (dissasembly benefits) with C# app, so I created a C++ Win32 Project (DLL) with export symbols like this:

LicensePolicy32.h:

```
// The following ifdef block is the standard way of creating macros which make exporting 
// from a DLL simpler. All files within this DLL are compiled with the LICENSEPOLICY32_EXPORTS
// symbol defined on the command line. This symbol should not be defined on any project
// that uses this DLL. This way any other project whose source files include this file see 
// LICENSEPOLICY32_API functions as being imported from a DLL, whereas this DLL sees symbols
// defined with this macro as being exported.
#ifdef LICENSEPOLICY32_EXPORTS
#define LICENSEPOLICY32_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LICENSEPOLICY32_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

LICENSEPOLICY32_API char* GetXmlTokenNode(void);
```

LicensePolicy32.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LicensePolicy32.h"

bool GetLicense()
{
    DWORD dwType = REG_SZ;
    HKEY hKey = 0;
    char value[1024];
    DWORD value_length = 1024;
    LPCWSTR subkey = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\WSESecurityPolicy";
    LONG openReg = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,subkey,0, KEY_WOW64_64KEY | KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey);
    if (openReg==ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    LONG getReg = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, L"WSEHostProcessID", NULL, &dwType, (LPBYTE)&value, &value_length);
    if (getReg==ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

LICENSEPOLICY32_API char* GetXmlTokenNode()
{
    char *orig;
    bool resultLicense = GetLicense();
    if (!resultLicense)
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        return "/{0}:Envelope/{0}:Header";
    }
}
```

My C# test code is as follows:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TestDllConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test testObj = new Test();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string result;

        [DllImport(@"D:\Proyectos\NET\Dll\LicensePolicy32\Release\LicensePolicy32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "GetXmlTokenNode")]
        public static extern string GetXmlTokenNode();

        public Test()
        {
            try
            {
                result = GetXmlTokenNode();
                result += " result";
            }
            catch (DllNotFoundException exDll)
            {
                string error = "Dll no encontrado";
            }
            catch (BadImageFormatException exBad)
            {
                string error = "Plataforma Ensamblado incompatible";
            }
            catch (Win32Exception exWin32)
            {
                string error = "Error general de Win32";
            }
            catch (EntryPointNotFoundException exPoint)
            {
                string error = "No encontró punto de entrada al método";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error = "Error otros";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Path to DLL is good, however when I run C# test project throws EntryPointNotFoundException.

I'd appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: You didn't guess at EntryPoint = "GetXmlTokenNode" correctly.  Let the linker create a .map file.  Or run Dumpbin.exe /exports on your DLL.  Either way you'll see the decorated name.  You also can't return a C string like that, the pinvoke marshaller is going to try to release the string, like it should.  That will bomb.  Declare it IntPtr instead and use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not the droids you are looking for.  Your c++ names will be decorated and the actual name will not be GetXmlTokenNode.  To avoid this, use extern "C" as part of the signature for the methods you want to export.  This will avoid name decoration.

You may find [this whitepaper](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3056/en/) useful.

Answer (score 0):

C++ compiler add a suffix to any function name. The suffix defines the parameter types and orders - that way the compiler can handle overloading.

To avoid it you can compile using C (change the cpp suffix to C, and if you don't have special C++ features in the code VS will understand what you want to do).

Alternatively find the real name of the native DLL function and use it as the entry point.

Comment: Actually Aaron's suggestion to add 'extern C' is better. I leave my answer for the overloading explanation.